# Fetch weekly data as a row based on monthly date range in DB2

Tags: db2

Is there a way to dynamically add the week ending date as column header in query from a monthly date range ? I have written the below query and its bringing in the desired result

```
select metername , sum(delta) from TABLE where metername='abc'
 AND (readingdate >= DATE ('2020-04-01')  AND readingdate < DATE ('2020-04-30') + 1 DAY)
 group by metername, week(readingdate);
```

Current Output

[image: CURRENT OUTPUT]

Expected output - **Also the heading should have the week ending date**

[image: output]

Comment: The number of columns may vary, so, you need to run ethier 1) Stored Procedure returning the result set / populating some temporary table or 2) Compound statement populating some temporary table. So, it's some procedure logic in any case.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cant! at least not in a SELECT statement.

the column/alias name by definition is a SQL Identifier.

> AS new-column-name
>   Names or renames the result column. The name must not be qualified and does not have to be unique. new-column-name is an *SQL identifier* of 128 UTF-8 bytes or less.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_selectclause.html

And a SQL identifier,  it's just a fixed name. can not be a result of an expression as you want. 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000720.html

As @Mark Barinstein suggested,  you would need a SP for this.